# Can I access an 'AWS DynamoDB' (managed?) DB from any other host?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm considering using the free-tier AWS Database (DynamoDB) but as they don't provide a free tier for hosting a NodeJS application, I'd like to use another service for that.
My question is: Can an application that lives in another cloud service, access a DB that lives in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, as long as you have the credentials to access DynamoDB, it doesn't matter where the client is running.